# xpath does not get the web element which has multiple classes

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am very new at Java and Selenium so my apologies in advance if my question sounds a bit primary.

I am using Selenium and Java to write tests. But have issue with finding elements. I know some other ways to find this WebElement,

but why this:

```
WebElement we1 =driverChrome.findElement(By.xpath
("//div[contains(@class,'elfinder-cwd-filename ui-draggable') and @title='project.CPG']"));
```

can not get this:

```
<div class="elfinder-cwd-filename ui-draggable" title="project.CPG">project.CPG</div>
```

and shows this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no 
such element: Unable to locate element:{"method":"xpath","selector":"
//div[contains(@class,'elfinder-cwd-filename ui-draggable') and @title='project.CPG']"}
```

this works:

```
WebElement we1 = driverChrome.findElement(By
.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'elfinder-cwd-filename') and @title='project.CPG']"));
```

but these ones do not work:

```
WebElement we1 = driverChrome.findElement(By
    .xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ui-draggable') and @title='project.CPG']"));


WebElement we1 = driverChrome.findElement(By.
xpath("//div[@class='elfinder-cwd-filename ui-draggable' and @title='project.CPG']"));
```

Sounds weird, this:

```
WebElement we = driverChrome.findElement(By
.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'combine-red')]"));
```

just worked for this:

```
    <div class="leaflet-marker-icon combine-red-off leaflet-zoom-hide leaflet-
clickable" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -17px; margin-top: -19px; left: 
149px; top: 302px; z-index: 10304; transform: rotate(450deg);"></div>
```

Comment: both should work, did you try waiting like I proposed? maybe some of the classes are loaded a bit later than you expect

Comment: @drkthng driverChrome.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driverChrome.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='elfinder-cwd-filename ui-draggable' and @title='project.CPG']")).click();  did not work

Comment: "did not work" means it threw the same error message that the element cannot be found? are you sure that you do not have typos in commands?

Comment: @drkthng it freezed for 30 sec and the throw **no such element: Unable to locate element**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but why this:
>
> ```
> WebElement we1 =driverChrome.findElement(By.xpath
> ("//div[contains(@class,'elfinder-cwd-filename ui-draggable') and @title='project.CPG']"));
> ```
>
> can not get this:
>
> ```
>  <div class="elfinder-cwd-filename ui-draggable" title="project.CPG">project.CPG</div>
> ```

Its because of Selenium's Class selector does not support Compound class names. Its search for exact class name (any part of compound class name), but not compound class name.

This code:

> ```
> WebElement we1 = driverChrome.findElement(By.
> xpath("//div[@class='elfinder-cwd-filename ui-draggable' and @title='project.CPG']"));
> ```

possibly can not work if there is some extra spaces or if on page generation classnames was change its place... like:

```
'elfinder-cwd-filename ui-draggable''
'elfinder-cwd-filename   ui-draggable '
```

or

```
'ui-draggable elfinder-cwd-filename'
```

and here...

> ```
>  WebElement we1 = driverChrome.findElement(By
>      .xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ui-draggable') and @title='project.CPG']"));
> ```

possibly you miss dot on the beginning. Try this:

```
WebElement we1 = driverChrome.findElement(By
          .xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'ui-draggable') and @title='project.CPG']"));
```

Comment: where and why should I put that dot ?

Comment: its means "All <div> elements one or more levels deep in the current context. ". I'm not sure about this situation, as I didnt saw html. But possibly this will solve your task.

Comment: List<WebElement> wes = driverChrome.findElements(By
    .xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'ui-draggable') and @title='project.CPG']"));  does not throw any Exception but freezes there

Comment: please, post html or give me link(better)

Answer (score 0):

When you write contains, try mentioning only one class without any space. IT should solve your issue. Here's how -

```
WebElement we1 =driverChrome.findElement(By.xpath
("//div[contains(@class,'elfinder-cwd-filename') and @title='project.CPG']"));
```

If you want to mention both the classes then give that without `contains` tag. Here's how -

```
WebElement we1 =driverChrome.findElement(By.xpath
("//div[@class='elfinder-cwd-filename ui-draggable' and @title='project.CPG']"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: first one worked but I need to check both classes in the same order, and the second one does not work

Comment: @LoveLovelyJava sorry there was a mistake in the syntax. Updated it. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

just try "=" instead of contains:

```
WebElement we1 =driverChrome.findElement(By.xpath
("//div[@class='elfinder-cwd-filename ui-draggable' and @title='project.CPG']"));
```

If it still does not work, it is possible that the element is not yet in the DOM when you are trying to find it, then you should try to place an implicit wait in front of your commands:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```